# JPA @ManyToOne foreign key not generated?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have two ManyToOne relationships in my application which are represented by Lists. For the relationship "ChapterSection - ManyToOne - Chapter, the foreign key is inserted in the table, when persisting the entity (in the table "ChapterSection" the foreign key for "Chapter" is stored). For the other relationship, which is "Chapter - ManyToOne - Document".

I use ddl.generation "drop-and-create-tables". In the Database I can see, that the column "Chapter.fk_document_iddocument" is marked as an indexed foreign key referenced to the document id. (I use EclipseLink and MySQL).

I don't see the difference between these two relationships and why one is working out but the other is not.

Document Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Document implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="iddocument")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="document_name")
    private String documentName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="Document", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Chapter> chapters;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="document_type")
    private DocumentTypes documentType;

//...getters, setters and other generated methods
```

Chapter Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Chapter implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idchapter")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="chapter_order")
    private int chapterOrder;

    @Column(name="parent_chapter")
    private Long parentChapter;

    @Column(name="chapter_name")
    private String chapterName;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_document_iddocument")
    private Document document;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="Chapter", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    List<ChapterSection> chapterSections;

//...getters, setters and other generated methods
```

ChapterSection Entity:

```
@Entity
public class ChapterSection implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idchaptersection")
    private Long idChapterSection;

    @Column(name="section_name")
    private String sectionName;

    @Column(name="section_order")
    private int sectionOrder;

    @Column(name="content")
    private String content;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_chapter_idchapter")
    private Chapter chapter;

 //...getters, setters and other generated methods
```

The method I create the document with:

```
public void createDocument() {

       List <Chapter> chapters = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
                Chapter chapter = new Chapter();
                chapter.setChapterOrder(i);
                chapter.setChapterName("Chapter "+i);
                List <ChapterSection> chapterSections = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++) {
                    ChapterSection chapterSection = new ChapterSection();
                    chapterSection.setChapter(chapter);
                    chapterSection.setSectionName("Chapter "+i+" Section");
                    chapterSection.setSectionOrder(j);
                    chapterSection.setContent("Kapitel "+i+ ", Section "+j+" Content!");
                    chapterSections.add(chapterSection);
                }
                chapter.setChapterSections(chapterSections);
                chapters.add(chapter);
            }


        document.setDocumentName("My Doc");
        document.setChapters(chapters);
        document.setDocumentType("My Doc Type");
        documentDAO.persistDocument(document);
}
```

Comment: Probably easily fixed if you can improve your question. What exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 3):

- The `mappedBy` element of the `@OneToMany` annotation is defined in the JPA spcification as follows:

> The field or property that owns the relationship. Required unless the relationship is unidirectional.

According to this definition your `mappedBy` elements must be set as (the value should be field name but not the class name):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="document", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<Chapter> chapters;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="chapter", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
List<ChapterSection> chapterSections;
```

- In you `createDocument()` method you haven't created the relationship between the `Document` and the `Chapter`. So you should tie them as follows:

  ```
  chapter.setDocument(document);
  ```

Comment: Ok, I see. So JPA doesn't recognize the the corresponding document by only adding the Chapters to the document? I would always have to explicitly set it?

Comment: In your case yes. You have defined bidrectional relationship so that you can access each of the entity from within the other.